# node.js image compression

Tags: image, node.js, compression

I'm looking for a node.js module.

A node.js module that I can use to serve compressed images of the sort by the smushit service.

Is there such a module?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe https://github.com/bentruyman/pulverizr?

Comment: This module is no longer in development. I suggest that you use GraphicsMagick recommended by @samant.

Answer (score 22):

maybe you can use `imagemin`

github:https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin

It can work.

Comment: it made my image grow! so sad!

Comment: Really crappy for single images or on-demand, sharp was the best.

Comment: Unfortunately it's now unmaintained

Answer (score 4):

I switched from `gm` to https://github.com/lovell/sharp for better performance.

Comment: could you please share the code to compress the image ? I only find to resize the image using sharp

Comment: Sharp's performance is great, but after using it a while, it can be problematic for multi-platform usage. It uses some native binaries, which vary depending on your operating system. Eventually had to ditch it.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone googling this, GraphicsMagic is hosted on NPM as gm: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gm

Comment: `GraphicsMagic`(gm) Is a nice tool but does not provide image optimization as the OP asked: > ...serve compressed images of the sort by the smushit service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GraphicsMagick](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html) for node.js.

Answer (score 2):

[Sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/).

- Supports TypeScript
- Simple easy to use API

Code

```
await sharp(file.path)
         .resize(600, 600)
         .toFile(file.path + '_compress')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this library  [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)  for node js

Answer (score 1):

Detected path and can use combination compressing. `SVG` `JPG` `PNG` `GIF`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-images

Comment: No support for promisses or typescript.

Comment: @OliverDixon already supports - Promised API

Comment: Светлов it has a crappy API, see my answer. Sharp is way better.

Answer (score 0):

for compression of image **compress-image** package is also good option
https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-images

Comment: Doesn't work on M1 from my testing.