# Compressing Images with Node.js and Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, google-cloud-storage

I would like to resize and compress images after users upload them to my site. It seems like there are quite a few options for resizing images with node (e.g. https://github.com/lovell/sharp), but I would like to compress the images as well in order to save disk space and allow for faster serving times. Is there a library or something else that makes this possible?

Here is a simplified version of my current (functioning) route as it stands today:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var bucket = require('../modules/google-storage-bucket');
var Multer = require('multer');
var multer = Multer({
  storage: Multer.memoryStorage(),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 // no larger than 5mb
  }
});

// Process the file upload and upload to Google Cloud Storage.
router.post('/', multer.single('file'), (req, res) => {

  // rejecting if no file is uploaded
  if (!req.file) {
    res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
    return;
  }

  // Create a new blob in the bucket and upload the file data.
  var blob = bucket.file('fileName');
  var blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();

  blobStream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('error', err);
    res.send(500);
  });

  blobStream.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('everything worked!')
  });

  blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073784/node-js-image-compression) you will find something useful :)

Comment: It seems like that library allows me to compress from the command line, I can do that, I just can't do it from my project on upload. Unless I'm misunderstanding this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience I would recommend [imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin). I've used it as a Gulp plugin, so you could 100% use in your project. But also you have to download the third-party modules: imagemin-pngquant and imagemin-jpegtran.

Hope you appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Sharp has API for adjusting image compression. For example:

https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#jpeg

Lists the options for JPEG write. You can adjust a range of knobs on the JPEG compressor to tune it for the performance/compression/quality tradeoff you want.

You can improve compression by up to about 30% in the best case, which honestly feels a bit marginal to me. It's unlikely to make a significant difference to your page size or your load times.

In terms of storage savings, the best solution is not to store images at all --- sharp is fast enough that you can simply generate all of your images on demand (most dynamic image resizing web proxies use sharp as the engine). That's a change that really will save you money and make your pages look better.